# Ошибка при добавлении записи в БД

Tags: php, mysql

Есть у меня в MySQL база `"baza"` и таблица `"posts"`.
Есть скрипт обработки формы и последующей записи данных в БД.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO posts (id, tema, text, smallpic, bigpic, data) VALUES (NULL, {$tema}, {$text}, {$smallpicture}, {$bigpicture}, NULL)";
echo $query;
mysql_query($query);
```

Причем `echo $query;` выводит всё так, как и должно быть, например:

```
INSERT INTO posts (id, tema, text, smallpic, bigpic, data)
    VALUES (NULL, Привет всем, gvjmnkmfgv, images/small/2015062412245745.jpg,
    images/big/2015062412245329.jpg, NULL)
```

А вот в базе ничего не появляется. Пытался через phpMyAdmin руками сделать вышеуказанный запрос, выдало ошибку:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax;
    check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
    for the right syntax to use near 'Ð²Ñ
```

Что я не так делаю?

Comment: все строки должны быть обернуты в одинарные либо двойные кавычки

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет, не всё в этом запросе так, как должно быть. Строковые константы должны быть в кавычках:

> INSERT INTO posts (id, tema, text, smallpic, bigpic, data) VALUES (NULL, 'Привет всем', 'gvjmnkmfgv', 'images/small/2015062412245745.jpg', 'images/big/2015062412245329.jpg', NULL)

PHP-код должен выглядеть примерно (на PHP не пишу, так что полной уверенности нет) так:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO posts (id, tema, text, smallpic, bigpic, data) VALUES (NULL, '{$tema}', '{$text}', '{$smallpicture}', '{$bigpicture}', NULL)";
```

Comment: О, спасибо! Теперь почти все работает как надо! Строка добавилась в бд. только почему-то вместо даты NULL так и вписался

Comment: @Anykey на здоровье. Возможно, потому, что вы в качестве даты передаёте `NULL`?

Comment: Может и так, я просто не совсем разобрался. Я думал, что там принцип как с автоинкрементом. У меня первый столбец id с автоинкрементом при передачи в него параметра NULL  он успешно увеличивается, с датой думал так же, передам NULL и дата встанет в момент добавления записи

Comment: @Anykey 1. Я лишь знаю, что можно установить `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` для поля типа `INT`. Про `DATE` ничего сказать не могу. 2. Ваш вопрос был про ошибку в SQL-запросе. Если ответ является правильным (для данного вопроса), отметьте его как правильный. Если с датой ничего не прояснится, и `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` вас не устраивает, то вы можете задать новый вопрос, описав в чем именно проблема с `DATE` и как вы пытались её исправить.